# Confused when setting an Emacs face

Tags: emacs, elisp

[image]
(set-face-attribute 'diredp-dir-heading nil
                    '(t (:foreground blue
                    :background dark1)))

What should be the right statements to set this face? Bow//

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please tell us exactly what you expect, and clearly tell us how the things you have tried aren't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Face attributes `:foreground` and `:background` must have **string** values.

So try `"blue"` instead of `blue` etc.

The error message you see is saying that you asked Emacs to evaluate `blue`, which means find its value as a variable. Emacs tried that and found that the symbol `blue` has no value as a variable.  The string `"blue"`, on the other hand, evaluates to itself, and a string is exactly the kind of value that is needed here.